# How can i access shared members in a another class

Tags: vb.net, shared

I have the following public class with shared members:

```
Public Module Modul1

Sub Main()
    Rectangle.Height = 3
End Sub

Public Class Rectangle
    Public Shared Length As Double
    Public Shared Height As Double

    Public Shared Function CalculatePerimeter#()
        Return (Length + Height) * 2
    End Function

    Public Shared Function CalcaulteArea#()
        Return Length * Height
    End Function
End Class
End Module
```

now i added a new class in vs (new tab) and tried to access the class Rectange

```
Public Class test
Rectangle.
End Class
```

But intelisence gives me nothing. Why can i not access the class? It is public and the members are shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are in a region where you can declare fields or properties or method bodies. Here you cannot access methods, properties or fields of other classes.

This would work:

```
Public Class test
    ' Rectangle.He...  <-- does not work because you can only use accessors or Dim etc.
    Dim height As Double = Rectangle.Height
End Class
```

Why should intellisense give you options that won't compile anyway?

Comment: thanks for solving and showing me how i can declare it in that space!

Comment: To be more precise, you *can* "Access" them as you have shown here. You cannot SET them in the declaration section of your code, but you can read thier values.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, you're right, of course. I should have called it "intellisense won't show you" since that's all   the question is about. So intellisense will show it if it makes sense. At the beginning of the line it doesn't make sense to access another class' property/field, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Modull.Rectangle
```

I think it should work.